# Unable to view fire simulation in rendered view

Tags: fire

I tried to create a smoke simulation in blender 2.8. I baked the data after I added the domain and flow object I can only see the fire in solid view and wireframe view but unable to see the fire animation (only smoke is visible) in material preview and rendered view. Can someone help me by explaining this

Comment: Could you specify Cycles or Eevee?

Comment: Its eevee render engine

Comment: My example below applies to both Eevee and Cycles with some tweaking of the node setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems "Quick Smoke" does not add any material to the Smoke Domain. Here is an example for Cycles.

[image]

[image]